# I use History.push to route component but it do not load jqueries

Tags: reactjs

I use this code to route component and it does not load jquery

```
class Index extends React.Component {
  render() {
   return (
    <div>
        <div className="col-12">
            <video autoPlay muted id="IntroVideo">
                <source src="assets/intro.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                <BrowserRouter>
                    {setTimeout(() => this.props.history.push('/home'), 6700)}
                </BrowserRouter>
            </video>
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

}
}

```
export default Index;
```

Comment: Please make sure your question is clear and you have a small example of the problem included. At the moment there is not enough information included to get any meaningful answers.

Comment: make sure your wherever you put this code must be encapsulate or wrap by `<BrowserRouter>whaevercodehere</BrowserRouter>` in order for it to work

Comment: I update the Code please help me i just want to route home component but it does not load jquery